# Creating Dataframe from csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with the following layout: year, race, sex, age and population. Each year has several different groups.

I created the following Dataframe from the CSV

```
CSV_df = pd.read_csv('Data/Demographics/Demo/akwbo19ages.csv') 

df = CSV_df[CSV_df["age"] >= 4].groupby(["year","race","sex","age"])['pop'].sum()
```

which results in

```
year  race  sex  age
1969  1     1    1      10574
                 2      20245
                 ...
                 n      11715
            2    1       8924
                 2       9919
                 ...
                 n       9960
                        ...  
2012  3     1    1       7861
                 2       8242
                 ...
                 n       7268
            2    1       7245
                 2       7821
                 ...
                 n       6912
```

However, what I would like to have is for each row to represent a single year and have several columns representing each group (i.e. columns with population figures for each possible combination of race, sex and age group)

```
year  group1  group2 ... groupN
1969  10574   20245      9960
...
2012  7861    8242       6912
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then by `list` comprehension rename columns `names`:

```
print s
year  race  sex  age
1969  1     1    1      10574
                 2      20245
            2    1       8924
                 2       9919
2012  3     1    1       7861
                 2       8242
            2    1       7245
                 2       7821
Name: a, dtype: int64


df = s.unstack().reset_index(drop=True, level=[1,2]).rename_axis(None)
df.columns = ['group' + str(col) for col in df.columns]
print df
      group1  group2
1969   10574   20245
1969    8924    9919
2012    7861    8242
2012    7245    7821
```

Or if you need `index name` remove [rename_axis](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename):

```
df = s.unstack().reset_index(drop=True, level=[1,2])
df.columns = ['group' + str(col) for col in df.columns]
print df
      group1  group2
year                
1969   10574   20245
1969    8924    9919
2012    7861    8242
2012    7245    7821
```